Which mechanism can achieve this?
I’m not very familiar with mechanism design, but I’m working on a project and could use some guidance. I have a hollow cylindrical structure with an open top and a closed bottom, and I need to place a smaller cylinder inside it. The goal is to use two springs to hold the smaller cylinder securely in the center, preventing it from moving up, down, or sideways.
The only solution I’ve come up with so far is to pull the springs outward to create enough space for the smaller cylinder to be inserted. However, I’d really like to incorporate a button mechanism that, when pressed inward, would compress the springs, making it easier to insert the smaller cylinder.
Which existing mechanisms that could achieve this?
I’ve also included a drawing to better illustrate what I’m trying to accomplish.


Without knowing anything of the real limitations I drew this:

It applies a simple idea: Outwards can be inwards when applied from the opposite side. It assumes the inner cylinder has a certain fixed diameter.
Insert a cage for the internal cylinder. Let it be made of a static half (blue) and a movable half (red), The cage can be quite sparse, I guess. The spring is written to be in the hinge, but it can be anywhere as long as it pushes or pulls the cage to the closed position.
Version 2: You can pull your own shafts with levers which turn pushing inwards to pulling outwards. And one movable shaft is theoretically enough if there's 3 shafts which have 120 degrees spacing (2 of the shafts are adjusted to certain depth). Pulling one shaft outwards shouldn't be too difficult. But the movement of the moving shaft should be strictly limited to happen axially - maybe by having 2 or more guide rods and high enough surface areas against the inner cylinder. That starts to be an alternative version of the cage idea.
Version 3: Push the interior cylinder between thin enough ailerons which get bent out of the way of the inserted cylinder. This, of course assumes that the surface of the inner cylinder is hard and straight and there's low friction so that pushing in and pulling out are possible. Balancing the forces so that the inner cylinder is well centered is easy if the number ailerons is high enough i.e. they are actually a circular brush and you have 2 of them - one near the top and one near the bottom. Stopping vertical motion needs a hard stopper, of course, and it must be opened for placing the inner cylinder or pulling it out.

@Russ   All these are based on no knowledge of your actual application and which practical limitations there exist. To get something really useful you should give more details.
